# Duplicate Row by condition and change type

Tags: r

I'm dealing with school data and I need to duplicate rows which serve larger grade spans that just ES or HS. Some sample code to illustrate my problem:

```r
# data
schools <- tibble(name = c("school a", "school b", "school c", "school z"), 
                  type = c("es", "NA", "hs", "es"),
                  gslo = c("01", "08", "09", "KG"),
                  gshi = c("12", "12", "12", "05"))
schools
  name     type  gslo  gshi 
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 school a es    01    12   
2 school b NA    08    12   
3 school c hs    09    12   
4 school z es    KG    05
```

Where `gslo` and `gshi` are the lowest and highest grades served, respectively. In the United States these would be divided into high schools or middle schools or elementary schools, the `type`.

Some schools serve more than just elementary grades, but are now only being counted as `type` == "es".

```
schools_attempt <- schools %>%
# add row based on condition and change type 
# not generalized 
  rbind(schools %>% filter(gslo == "01", gshi == "12") %>% mutate(type = "hs"))
> schools_attempt
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  name     type  gslo  gshi 
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 school a es    01    12   
2 school b NA    08    12   
3 school c hs    09    12   
4 school z es    KG    05   
5 school a hs    01    12
```

This works but is not general. Is it possible to avoid a huge case_when? Note the changed school type classification (es -> hs)

```
schools_want <- tibble(name = c("school a", "school b", "school c", "school z", "school a"), 
                       type = c("es", "NA", "hs", "es", "hs"),
                       gslo = c("01", "08", "09", "KG", "01"),
                       gshi = c("12", "12", "12", "05", "12"))
> schools_want
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  name     type  gslo  gshi 
  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 school a es    01    12   
2 school b NA    08    12   
3 school c hs    09    12   
4 school z es    KG    05   
5 school a hs    01    12
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear about the condition in `filter`.  Is it based on always 01 and 12 or is it different (as you mentioned case_when)

Comment: I can edit to make this clearer. Thanks. There would be multiple filter conditions related to the gshi/gslo values.

Comment: Here we add an "hs" row for any school going to grade 9+ that isn't already marked as such. `schools %>% rbind(schools %>% filter(type != "hs", parse_number(gshi) >= 9) %>% mutate(type = "hs"))`.  Are there more data cleaning conditions than that?    [That's `readr::parse_number()`, loaded with `library(tidyverse)`]

Comment: Thank you. I do think this needs to be done using `parse_number` and possibly if i append a "_hs" to the `type` I can then pass it through `separate` to add the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might suffice as a general approach. If it starts in grade 9+, it's a high school. If it ends before grade 9, it's an elementary. Otherwise, it's both and we can split into two rows.

```
library(dplyr)
schools %>% 
  mutate(across(gslo:gshi, ~if_else(.x == "KG", 0, as.numeric(.x))),
         type2 = case_when(
           gslo >= 9 ~ "hs",
           gshi <= 8 ~ "es",
           TRUE ~ "hs, es"
         )) %>%
  separate_rows(type2)



# A tibble: 6 x 5
  name     type   gslo  gshi type2
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 school a es        1    12 hs   
2 school a es        1    12 es   
3 school b NA        8    12 hs   
4 school b NA        8    12 es   
5 school c hs        9    12 hs   
6 school z es        0     5 es
```

---

Edit: if you want to preserve the gslo/gshi columns as-is, add `.names = "{.col}_num"),` to the `across()` call and use `gslo_num` and `gshi_num` in the case_when.